# Promise - passar argumento para um construtor sem parâmetro

Tags: javascript, promises

A Promise possui um construtor de função sem parâmetros que é esse:

```
function Promise() {
}
```

de onde tirei isso?
do console do navegador digitando `Promise.prototype.constructor`

Como que o construtor acima vai receber o argumento dessa Promise por exemplo:

```
new Promise ( (resolve, reject) => {} )
```

já que ele não tem nome de parâmetro pra receber nenhum tipo de argumento.

Comment: Por que ao invés de voar as cegas formulando hipóteses equivocas você não lê a documentação? Veja [MDN Web Docs - constructor Promise()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise) e veja também [MDN Web Docs - Usando promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

Comment: O construtor tem um parâmetro, que é a função com os parâmetros `resolve` e `reject`. Isso está descrito na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise) e [especificação da linguagem](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/control-abstraction-objects.html#sec-promise-constructor). Uma forma de ver quantos parâmetros tem é `Promise.prototype.constructor.length`, que é `1` (ou seja, ele tem um parâmetro sim). O que acontece é que os objetos *built-in* são mostrados no console de forma "genérica", sem especificar os parâmetros.

Comment: Tem alguns problemas com a sua pergunta e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Antes de usar o site faça o [tour] e leia [ask]. Também fique por dentro do que é um [mcve] e para entender qual a finalidade da plataforma leia [help].

Comment: Sugestão de leitura [W3Schools é uma referência horrível, certo?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/692/137387)

Comment: A conversa ficou longa e foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152126/discussion-on-question-by-murilo-jr-promise-passar-argumento-para-um-construto);. Caso seja necessário adicionar algo, utilizem o link fornecido.